# instantiate VM with file inside

Tags: terraform, cloud-init

I have a terraform file to create a VM with a cloud-init configuration, that puts a file at location A with content 'CONTENT'. In particular, for openstack but I think that doesn't matter too much:

```
resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "VM" {
  name              = "VM1"
  user_data         = file("userdata_file")
}
```

The `userdata_file` then contains the following block:

```
write_files:
  - path: A
   content: |
      CONTENT

#some other stuff ...
```

That works all pretty nicely, but: I would want to have the file `A` as it own file in the repository. That is, there would be a plain text file `A`  with the `CONTENT` inside , and ideally I could reference it either in the `userdata_file` or in the Terraform file. Something along the lines of

```
write_files: 
 - path: A
   content: readFromFile('A')  #this doesn't exist AFAIK
```

Is there some possibility to do this easily with Terraform ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function to read a file at a specific path and return its contents as a string is the `file` function, and you demonstrate you are already using it so you should be familiar with it already. The missing piece of the puzzle here is to render the file content of `userdata_file` dynamically. The `templatefile` function is typically utilized for this functionality as it allows separated string expression resolution:

```
resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "VM" {
  name              = "VM1"
  user_data         = templatefile("userdata_file", {})
}
```

and then as you would expect:

```
write_files: 
- path: A
  content: ${file('A')}
```

Comment: This works in principle but a word of caution to users: In this case, the result still needs to be valid yaml for cloud-init. So watch out for multiline string, single and double quotes and resulting indentation.